# How are nested if-else loops resolved in BASIC

Tags: nested, 8051, basic

I've got this legacy code I'm analyzing:

```
If (X) then
    if Cnt < 4 then Cnt = Cnt + 1 ; 4 samples
Else
    if Cnt > 0 then Cnt = Cnt-1   ; keep history
EndIf
```

Which has `Cnt` go up and down depending on `X`

And I'm wondering if that else statement acts like their indention implies they think it does.

The code might be interpreted more like:

```
If (X) then
    if Cnt < 4 then 
        Cnt = Cnt + 1 ; 4 samples
    Else
        if Cnt > 0 then 
            Cnt = Cnt-1   ; keep history
EndIf
```

In which `Cnt` get to 4 and then toggles on/off if X is true.

This is basic as compiled using BCI51. That's a basic compiler for an 8051 from back in 1990 by Systronix.

How do nested if-else pairs get resolved in basic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember how QBasic did so, and I'm going to assume that this complier is doing the same. This is really tugging on my memory, so I might be wrong.

If a `IF THEN` is followed by code on the same line, then it is fully contained. Therefore

```
if Cnt < 4 then Cnt = Cnt + 1
else
   ...
```

would be illegal and you must place the `Cnt = Cnt + 1` on it's own line to create a multi-line `IF` statement. Therefore, the `ELSE` is paired the topmost `IF`

Since, in the original code, the `Cnt = Cnt + 1` and `Cnt = Cnt - 1` are on the same lines as the `IF THEN`, I would interpret the code as follows:

```
If (X) then
    If Cnt < 4 Then
        Cnt = Cnt + 1 ; 4 samples
    EndIf
Else
    If Cnt > 0 Then
        Cnt = Cnt-1   ; keep history
    EndIf
EndIf
```

So, yes, I believe the code operates as the indentation implies.

Are you able to modify the code and test if you see any changes?

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of the same-line aspect of basic.  And yeah, modifying the code is easy but testing it requires an 8051 chip to put it on. The powers that be don't want to let me touch their production unit. Hmmm, yeah, the safest route would be to get an 8051 and test this out.

Comment: This is correct, the same-line aspect implies an end-if which means it works as intended. Which is a load off my chest. Thanks Dr. Robot Ninja.